# Need help converting a model into multiple cubes/shapes

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, objects

I am currently working on a suspended installation of cardboard cubes, or tubes, that delegates write on and an install team will hang to create an icon. By the end of the event there will be a finished piece.

To visualise this I am looking to create this on Blender however I am having trouble creating this. Is there a process I could use in Blender that could translate a model into these separate shapes to save me from manually creating this?

Thank you!

[image: Plane out of Paper]

[image: Butterfly out of cubes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Geometry Nodes* are probably the best way to do it, but you can try it with *Particle > Hair*:

[image]

Build the object (the plane), give it a particle system. Enable the *Advanced* option to have some rotation options, under *Emission* choose the number of particles, also choose *Source > Emit From > Volume*. Under *Rotation* choose the way the particles are oriented.

Under *Render > Render As* choose *Object*, and *Instance Object* > choose the object that is used as particle. Deactivate *Show Emitter*. Deactivate it also under *Viewport Display*:

[image]

If you need more particles in some parts of the object, paint it in *Weight Paint* mode and in the *Particle* panel, under *Vertex Groups > Density*, choose the group you've created.

Comment: This is great thank you so much for your help!